# Number of way to split $n$ people into nonempty committees with at least 1 chairperson

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, generating-functions

I need to find an exponential generating function for the number of way to split $n$ people into nonempty committees with at least 1 chairperson. I am struggling greatly with EGFs...

Anyways if we removed the requirement of needing one chair person I can see that the EGF could just be defined as $G(x) = \sum_{0}^{\infty}S(n,k) \frac{x^n}{n!}$ which has a well known closed form (S(n,k) here are the stirling numbers of the first kind. I am unsure how to incorporate the requirement of a chairperson. I see for any committee with $k$ people there are $k$ possibilities for chairperson, but what would we do? Multiply it into the EGF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an application of the exponential formula. Consider the EGF
of the same question expect you insist on just **one** committee. For
$n$ people there are $n$ ways to do it, so the answer is $G(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n/n!=xe^x$. So the exponential generating function you seek is the exponential of this, to wit, $F(x)=\exp(xe^x)$.

Comment: Why is it the exponential of $G(x)$?

Comment: @Boots The EGF for $k$ committees is $G(x)^k/k!$.

Comment: How would we get this as the EGF? For example this is not in the form $a_{k} \frac{x^k}{k!}$

Comment: @Boots You could start by thinking about the EGF of case when there are two committees.

Comment: For each committee we want to describe the number of ways to choose a chairperson, which the function $G(x)$ describes?